# Heavy MySQL load

Tags: mysql

Looking at `top` right now, I have this:

> `PID   USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND`
>   `12989 mysql     20   0 7366m 826m 6972 S 486.8  2.1   5518:14 mysqld`

Needless to say, this seems a little high. I've checked `show processlist` and I see a lot of `update` and `updating` status queries. It should be noted that the site, being a game, is *extremely* busy and intensive on select, update and insert queries.

Is there any way to narrow down what's causing the bottleneck here? Any variables that can be adjusted, for instance?

Comment: that's not high. it's just mysql running on multiple cores and doing what it's supposed to. given you see lots of update queries, you're probably disk i/o-bound and there's not much you can tune in mysql

Comment: Start with mysqltuner.pl: http://mysqltuner.com/

Comment: @MarcB The load spike seems to have settled, but if it peaks again I'll check the disk activity.

Comment: @MarcB Yup, I'm getting 5%wa right now. Thanks for the pointer.